# Question regarding stress, force, and area

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

I came across this question recently.[image]

I understand that stress = force/area.
I understand that the total force is 8kN.
So what I tried to do was substitute the values for Area given in the question and find the corresponding stress value and see whether they matched. Using that method, I got the answer as A, but turns out, the answer is D. I have no clue how they got this. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Hmmm, to find the stress in such a situation, would you not use the same idea of substitution? I think you'd get the same answer of A?

Comment: Hi Elijah and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: @JohnRennie Awww, that's a shame. This is a past paper question, not homework, just practice for my exams. I understand tho, and I'll stick to the guidelines. I don't expect you to work it out for me, but could you hint at another direction at which I can tackle this problem?

Comment: *I understand that the total force is 8kN,* is not a correct statement.

Comment: @Farcher Thank you! I think I've understood where I went wrong now.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant force is not 8kN.

Imagine pushing on a wall with 4kN. The wall responds with 4kN the other way due to Newton's 3rd law, but it is still only being pressed upon with 4kN. Same argument can be used for each slice throughout the shown metallic beam. You cannot deform an object with a larger force than you are supplying.

Comment: Oo, that's quite interesting. Thanks a ton! I think I've understood where I went wrong.